# Get the background of an ImageButton as a bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I have a `canvas` and an `ImageButton`. I am trying to get the background image of my `ImageButton` and set it as the background image of my canvas. My canvas uses the `drawBitmap()` function to set it's background, so it takes in a bitmap. However, the `getBackground()` function for my `ImageButton` returns a drawable.

How do I get the background of my `ImageButton` and set it to the background of my canvas?

Comment: post some of your code...

Answer (score 1):

```
canvas.setBackground(drawableFromImageButton.getConstantState().newDrawable());
```

when canvas is view, setBackground method is applicable.

Comment: The Canvas I'm using is a custom class that extends view, not androids Canvas, so im not sure if this would work. Also, it's not letting me call `clone()` on the image button drawable.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Bitmap`  from the `Drawable` as following way

```
Drawable drawable = imageButton.getBackground();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this. it might be helpful.

```
Drawable drawable = imageButton.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
```

after that call

```
canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: I get the following `android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable`

Answer (score 0):

If you making a custom Canvas you can directly set drawable to set the background.

Follow this-

```
customCanvas.setBackground(imageview.getBackground());
```

The documentation says like tbis-

```
void  setBackground(Drawable background)
```

Set the background to a given Drawable, or remove the background.

The draw is used only to draw on tope of the canvas.

I hope this would help you.